# asset path doesn't work with "/android_asset/" path

Tags: android, android-file, android-assets

I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/oupson/Kapng-Android), like this:

```
        val imageUrl = "file:///android_asset/error_apng.png"
        val animator = ApngAnimator(this@MainActivity).loadInto(iv_circle)
        animator.load(imageUrl)
        animator.play()
```

But it shows nothing. However, the sample url with `https://`works fine.

I tried with the followings:

`file://android_asset/error_apng`

`file:///android_asset/apng/error_apng`

`asset://error_apng.pn`

`assets://error_apng.png`

`assets://error_apng.png`

The `README.md` says I can use `url` or `file path`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: where is the file present, either in your project directory or in phone SD card?

Comment: It's in `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library doesn't seem perfect. Try using this library instead:
https://github.com/penfeizhou/APNG4Android

Comment: APNG4Android with glide still not animate the asset file  for me. Why ?

Comment: @Victor Choy, please post new question with your code and situation.

Comment: I sovled my problem by read and debug sources. The main resean is caches produced from the image by glide. The cache cause asset file not appear right. Very annoying. @c-an

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
val file = File("file:///android_asset/error_apng.png")
val animator = ApngAnimator(this@MainActivity).loadInto(iv_circle)
animator.load(file)
animator.play()
```

If it doesn't work then try hosting your image in a image hosting website and use the url.

Comment: It says in the comment of example source. `// image url could be an url, or a file path. You could also load byteArray and file`

Comment: @c-an Sorry. Missed that comment. Did you try initializing it as `File("file path")`?. The method implementation does seem to have support for url, uri and file, so it should work.